# How to find the size of the padding in d3.js scaleBand

Tags: d3.js

I'm making sparklines next to bar charts but trying to get the positioning right.

The bars are set out with d3.scaleBand().paddingInner(0.1)

I'm translating the line paths by y.bandwidth() which gets me close (see below).

It looks like it needs to add a bit more for the padding. How much is the padding? It's set at 0.1 but 0.1 of what? How do I find out the padding in pixel to add to the translate?

[image: bar chart with sparklines]

Code is currently at https://github.com/henryjameslau/new-trade-map/blob/master/worldmap/index2.html

Answer (score 3):

After reading the readme for [d3-scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#band_paddingOuter) it says

> The inner padding determines the ratio of the range that is reserved
>   for blank space between bands.

so the answer is 0.1 of the range which is set in d3.scaleBand

I am now translating the paths by i*(y.bandwidth()+0.1*y.bandwidth())+0.05*y.bandwidth()

[image: Chart and sparklines]

Answer (score 0):

The padding function allows you to set padding between the bands, and above and below, as seen below in the documentation.

[image: d3 scale band documentation]

My suggestion would be to add whatever padding you need to your y translation.